# How to generate a NUL-delimited stream of timestamped filenames with BSD `stat` command

Tags: bash, macos, awk, stat, bsd

Let's suppose that you need to generate a `NUL`-delimited stream of timestamped filenames.

On Linux & Solaris I can do it with:

```bash
stat --printf '%.9Y %n\0' -- *
```

On BSD, I can get the same info, but delimited by newlines, with:

```bash
stat -f '%.9Fm %N' -- *
```

The `man` talks about a few escape sequences but the `NUL` byte doesn't seem supported:

> If the `%` is immediately followed by one of `n`, `t`, `%`, or `@`, then a `newline` character, a `tab` character, a `percent` character, or the current file number is printed.

Is there a way to work around that? <sub>**edit:** (accurately and efficiently?)</sub>

---

**Update:**

- Sorry, the glob `*` is misleading. The arguments can contain any path.
- I have a working solution that forks a `stat` call for each path. I want to improve it because of the massive number of files to process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. What you can do** (accurate but slow):

Fork a `stat` command for each input path:

```bash
for p in "$@"
do
    stat -nf '%.9Fm' -- "$p" &&
    printf '\t%s\0' "$p"
done
```

---

**2. What you can do** (accurate but twisted):

In the input paths, replace each occurrence of (possibly overlapping) `/././` with a single `/./`, make `stat` output `/././\n` at the end of each record, and use `awk` to substitute each `/././\n` by a `NUL` byte:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob

stat -nf '%.9Fm%t%N/././%n' -- "${@//\/.\/+(.\/)//./}" |

awk -F '/\\./\\./' '{
    if ( NF == 2 ) {
        printf "%s%c", record $1, 0
        record = ""
    } else
        record = record $1 "\n"
}'
```

**N.B.** If you wonder why I chose `/././\n` as record separator then take a look at [Is it "safe" to replace each occurrence of (possibly overlapped) `/./` with `/` in a path?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/717506/504798)

---

**3. What you should do** (accurate & fast):

You can use the following `perl` one‑liner on almost every UNIX/Linux:

```bash
LANG=C perl -MTime::HiRes=stat -e '
    foreach (@ARGV) {
        my @st = stat($_);
        if ( @st > 0 ) {
            printf "%.9f\t%s\0", $st[9], $_;
        } else {
            printf STDERR "stat: %s: %s\n", $_, $!;
        }
    }
' -- "$@"
```

**note:** for `perl < 5.8.9`, remove the `-MTime::HiRes=stat` from the command line.

---

#### ASIDE: There's a bug in BSD's `stat`:

When `%N` is at the end of the format string and the filename ends with a `newline` character, then its trailing `newline` might get stripped:

For example:

```bash
stat -f '%N' -- $'file1\n' file2
```

```
file1
file2
```

For getting the output that one would expect from `stat -f '%N'` you can use the `-n` switch and add an explicit `%n` at the end of the format string:

```bash
stat -nf '%N%n' -- $'file1\n' file2
```

```
file1

file2
```

Comment: In the 2nd script, best I can tell it'd be simpler to work with `//` instead of `/././`, i.e. change every `/+` in the path to `/` then add `//` to the end of the stat output and use `//` as the awk FS. The awk script could be reduced too, so the whole script after the shopt would just be `stat -nf '%.9Fm%t%N//%n' -- "${@//+(\/)//}" | awk -F'//' '{printf "%s", $1; if (NF==1) print ""; else printf "%c", 0}'`

Comment: @EdMorton I chose `/././` because it's not safe to replace `//` nor `/./` by `/` (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/717506/504798)

Comment: @EdMorton You're right, it's easier to print on-the-fly than to rebuilding the record. To be accurate the `if (NF==1)` should be `if (NF<2)`; there might be a filename with `\n\n` in it ;-)

Comment: Interesting about `//path`, thanks - you should mention that reasoning in your answer as otherwise the choice of `/././` over `//` seems arbitrary. Regarding "might be a filename with `\n\n` in it" - I don't see how that would make any difference since the script is just replacing every `/././\n` with `\0` so AFAIK however many `\n`s appear in other contexts would be irrelevant.

Comment: when a filename contains `\n\n` there will be a `NF==0`; try your code with `printf '%s//\n' $'a\n' $'b\n\n' $'c\n\n\n' | awk -F'//' '{printf "%s", $1; if (NF==1) print ""; else printf "%c", 0}' | xargs -0 bash -c '"$0" "$@"' printf '%q\n'` , the empty lines in the filenames are skipped

Comment: Ah, that's true.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this work-around solution if running `stat` command for files:

```bash
stat -nf "%.9Fm %N/" * | tr / '\0'
```

Here:

- `-n`: To suppress newlines in `stat` output
- Added `/` as terminator for each entry from `stat` output
- `tr / '\0'`: To convert `/` into NUL byte

---

Another work-around is to use a control character in `stat` and use `tr` to replace it with `\0` like this:

```bash
stat -nf "%.9Fm %N"$'\1' * | tr '\1' '\0'
```

This will work with directories also.

Comment: Thank you anubhava, you should specify that it only works for pure filenames

Comment: @Fravadona: Noted in question. Also added another option to work with directories.

Comment: Replacing a control char with an other one doesn't feel like a good method

Comment: Well every solution will be a work around only since stay on Mac doesn’t have this capability built. I have mentioned both being work around solutions only.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `stat` out of the box does not offer this option, and so what you ask is not directly achievable.

However, you can easily implement the required functionality in a scripting language like Perl or Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pathlib import Path
from sys import argv

for arg in argv[1:]:
    print(
        Path(arg).stat().st_mtime,
        arg, end="\0")
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/vXiSPY

The demo exhibits a small discrepancy in the mtime which does not seem to be a rounding error, but the result could be different on MacOS (the demo platform is Debian Linux, apparently). If you want to force the result to a particular number of decimal places, Python has formatting facilities similar to those of `stat` and `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

With any command that can't produce NUL-terminated (or any other character/string terminated) output, you can just wrap it in a function to call the command and then `printf` it's output with a terminating NUL instead of newline, for example:

```
nulstat() {
    local fmt=$1 file
    shift
    for file in "$@"; do
        printf '%s\0' "$(stat -f "$fmt" "$file")"
    done
}

nulstat '%.9Fm %N' *
```

For example:

```
$ > foo

$ > $'foo\nbar'

$ nulstat '%.9Fm %N' foo* | od -c
0000000    1   6   6   3   1   6   2   5   3   6   .   4   7   7   9   8
0000020    0   1   4   0       f   o   o  \0   1   6   6   3   1   6   2
0000040    5   3   9   .   3   8   8   0   6   9   9   3   0       f   o
0000060    o  \n   b   a   r  \0
0000066
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to work around that?

If all you need is to just replace all newlines with NULLs, then following [`tr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) should suffice

```
stat -f '%.9Fm %N' * | tr '\n' '\000'
```

Explanation: `000` is `NULL` expressed as octal value.

Comment: This might cause issue if filename has newline character (which is one of the possible reasons to generate NUL separated filenames).

Comment: It's a simple and pragmatic solution, +1, but @Sundeep is right, it isn't bullet-proof.

Comment: @Fravadona if you are working with only filenames (i.e without directory paths), then see if you can add `/` at the end of your `stat` invocation and then change `/` to NUL (since filenames cannot have `/`)

Comment: If the user could rely on LFs not appearing in file names then they could use LF-terminated `stat` output instead of NUL-terminated.